# What does "life" mean here?

Tags: soul-2020

In *Soul* (2020), Jerry explains about spark to unborn souls:

> Jerry: Maybe you will find their spark in the Hall of Everything,
> where literally anything on Earth could inspire. Or perhaps you'll
> prefer the Hall of You, featuring a selection of moments from your own
> inspiring **life**.

What does "life" mean here? He explaining to unborn souls who doesn't experience life yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the mentor can use aspects of their own life to show how inspiring life can be for the new soul.

In this case, Joe can show aspects of his life to inspire the unborn life to find their spark and be born.